# If $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ are the roots of $z^3=1$, and $|w_1|=|w_2|=|w_3|=1$, then $z_0$ exists such that $\sum_{cyc} |z_1-z_0|\leq\sum_{cyc}|w_1-z_0|$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> Let complex numbers $z_{1}$, $z_{2}$, $z_{3}$ be distinct roots of the equation $$z^{3}=1$$ Given complex numbers $w_{1}$, $w_{2}$, $w_{3}$, and $$\left|w_{1}\right|=\left|w_{2}\right|=\left|w_{3}\right|=1,$$
> prove that there exist a complex number $z_{0}$ such that $$\left|z_{1}-z_{0}\right|+\left|z_{2}-z_{0}\right|+\left|z_{3}-z_{0}\right| \leqslant\left|w_{1}-z_{0}\right|+\left|w_{2}-z_{0}\right|+\left|w_{3}-z_{0}\right|.$$

This is a problem which I met, and I was told that this question can be solved by finding its geometric meaning and using Ptolemy's theorem. I'm finding the solution related to this hint or some other better solutions, and the source of this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the geometric interpretation of this problem? If you are familiar with complex numbers / Argand diagrams then it should be easy to at least draw or describe a diagram, which you have not yet done...

Comment: [This link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/roots-of-unity/) may be helpful. Scroll down to get the geometrical interpretation of roots of unity.

Comment: The cube roots of unity lie on a unit circle at angles of 0,120,240. The three given complex numbers also lie on a unit circle with origin as the centre. Also, the expression | z1 - z2| represemts the distance between the points z1 and z2.

Comment: I see. So I only need to prove that there exist a complex number z lie on the unit circle, such that the sum of distances from z to a set of trisection points is less than or equal to the sum of distances from z to 3 given complex number which lies on the unit circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the points $z_i$ are three evenly distributed points on the unit circle while $w_i$ are three arbitrary points on the same unit circle. If we also let $z_0$ be any point on this unit circle, we may immediately use Ptolemy's theorem on the quadrilateral spanned by the $z_i$. This leads to a (surprisingly simple) equation, which in particular implies the following: If $P$ and $Q$ are points on the unit circle lying 120 degrees apart, and $R$ is any point on the arc spanned by $P$ and $Q$, then $|PR|+|QR| \geq \sqrt{3}$. Extending the angle between $P$ and $Q$ clearly makes the sum $|PR|+|QR|$ larger, so the inequality must hold for such pairs of points as well.

There are two cases. First assume that one of the arcs spanned by the $z_i$ contains at least two of the points $w_j$. Let $z_k$ be the point opposite of this arc and let $z_0 = z_k$. Then this $z_0$ clearly satisfies inequality stated in the problem.

The second case is to assume that all arcs spanned by the $z_i$ contains exactly one $w_j$. Pick two points $w_i$ and $w_j$ separated by an arc length of at least 120 degrees (such a pair must necessarily exist). Let $z_k$ be the single point lying on the arc spanned by $w_i$ and $w_j$. The above inequality may now be used to show that $z_0 = z_k$ satisfies the inequality stated in the problem.

Comment: Or, the inequality $|PR|+|QR|\geq\sqrt{3}$ actually follows from the triangle inequality... Not certain how you're supposed to use Ptoltemy's theorem then.

Comment: Also not always true that extending the angle between $P$ and $Q$ will make the sum $|PR|+|QR|$ larger. (It is true if one does not extend it beyond 240 degrees)